# Not able to apply filter through common search box on geometry type on IQueryable object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, exception, predicate

This is my detailed code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8nBV.png)

could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

This is the exception I am getting , tried by converting Latitude and longtitude in int and string but not gettig any luck.

Seeking for suggestions :)

Comment: Please don't post photos of your code, but the code itself.

Comment: But I think the issue is with your linq statement in the sql query. The "bool ? value1 : value2" syntax, forget what its called at the moment

Comment: @JBatstone  I did not get any issue  in the condition checked by modifying it, this is only a simple piece of code, I have tried multiple conversions and conditions to resolve this issue . but issue remains same. Thank you :)